# Javascript: Changing a string in a table on click

Tags: javascript

I'm on a Javascript class (still pretty new to the language) and trying to get my head around this problem. Basically I need to add an event listener which changes a string in a `<td>` row to something else when clicked on.

Now in theory what I've written below should work (I think) but for some reason `k[i]` returns an undefined value. Below is within a new function which triggers on page load:

```
var k = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for( var i = 0; i < k.length; i++ ){
    k[i].addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        k[i].textContent = "Success!";
    });
}
```

If someone could help me get my head around where I'm going wrong I'd be really grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    evt.target.textContent = "Success!";
```

Instead of :

```
    k[i].textContent = "Success!";
```

Good Luck ! Demo is below

```js
var k = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for( var i = 0; i < k.length; i++ ){
    k[i].addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        evt.target.textContent = "Success!"; // ⚠️ So you have to do this
    });
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are Welcome 

Answer (score 1):

As Tomas said, the issue is with your variable scope, as an alternative to his answer you can use `this` keyword.
Here's a working fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/d9pzyf15/1/

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="thing"> 1 </td>
    <td class="thing"> 2 </td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

JS

```
let tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td')
for(let i = 0; i < tds.length; i++){
  tds[i].addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    this.textContent = 'Changed'
  });
}
```

**EDIT**

As suggested by Abdennour in the comments, this would be the answer using ES6 arrow functions

```
let tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td')
for(let i = 0; i < tds.length; i++){
  tds[i].addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    ev.target.textContent = 'Changed'
  });
}
```

Comment: `this` valid with callback as a simple function .. not valid with a callback as arrow function. . In two cases, `event.target` is valid

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI Interesting, I didn't know this, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is variable scope. When event listener is called `i` is different from time when event listener was created so `k[i]` contains undefined variable. Solution is written by Abdennour TOUMI

Answer (score 0):

The problem as mentioned is scope.

You can use the `target` like @abdennour mentions, but sometimes these might not be available.

The easiest way to capture scope if using `esnext` stuff, is use `let` to capture the var,..

Another way if using `es5`, is use a self invoking anonymous function to capture..

Below are the three examples, the `esNext` one's is commented out.  The second `esnext` one uses the the new `for of`, construct.. please note, not `for in`..

```js
var k = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for( var i = 0; i < k.length; i++ ){
  (function (e) {
    e.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
      e.textContent = "Success!";
    });
  })(k[i]);
}

/*or use esnext stuff*/
/*for( var i = 0; i < k.length; i++ ){
    let e = k[i];    
    e.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        e.textContent = "Success!";
    });
}*/

/*or maybe use the for of.. note not for in*/
/*
for (let e of document.getElementsByTagName("td")) {
  e.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    e.textContent = "Success!";
  });
}*/
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>one</td>
<td>two</td>
<td>three</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```